# Intenet on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: internet, 16.04

I'm having trouble connecting to the internet on Ubuntu. I did try to set up a wireless connection in the connection settings but that has not worked, I checked if Wi-Fi spots were listed but it doesn't even list anything. I did check to see if the wireless adapters were on in the command line but it didn't mention the wireless one, just the Ethernet adapter. I think the card is perhaps disabled? I have Windows on another partition and the internet is fine, so its definitely not my computer. I'm new to Ubuntu so help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

James.

Comment: You'll have to specify the type of wireless hardware you are using so that we can help you to ensure you have proper drivers installed to use it.  What is the name and manufacturer of the wireless adapter?  Also give us the output of: `sudo lshw -C network` and the output of `lsusb`